# How do I correctly performance test SELECT queries with Oracle?

Tags: performance, oracle

I would like to test two queries to find out their performance as apposed to just looking at the execution plan. I have seen Tom Kyte do this all the time on his website as a way to gather evidence on his theories.

I believe there are many pitfalls in performance testing, for example, when i run a query in SQL developer for the first time, that query might return some fair number. Running that exact same query again, returns instantaneously. There must be some sort of caching on the server or client going on and I understand this is important - however I am only interested in non cached performance.

What are the guidelines to performance test? AND how do I write a performance test which repeats the query? Do i just write an anonymous block & loop? How do i get timing information, averages, medians, std deviations?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179512/how-to-disable-oracle-cache-for-performance-tests

Comment: To all responders, as a developer, i feel hopeless. I don't have the knowledge or tools. :|

Answer (score 2):

Oracle (and other databases) cache queries, which is where you see the behavior you describe.  A "hard" parse means there's no query plan for the query, which leaves Oracle to figure out the query plan based on indexes and statistics.  A "soft" parse is what happens when you run the ***identical query*** afterwards, and receive an instantaneous result, because the query plan exists & Oracle re-uses it.  See [the Ask Tom question about it for more details](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2588723819082).

Be aware of the [EXPLAIN output](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm):

> With the cost-based optimizer, execution plans can and do change as the underlying costs change. EXPLAIN PLAN output shows how Oracle runs the SQL statement when the statement was explained. This can differ from the plan during actual execution for a SQL statement, because of differences in the execution environment and explain plan environment.

Focusing on the non-cached performance gives a worst-case scenario, but given that caching will occur - non-cached benchmarks aren't realistic in everyday use.

Comment: Hi OMG Ponies, your Jedi is most powerful. I updated my question. How do go about timing a query and running it repeatedly?

Comment: @JavaRocky: Timing a query is at the mercy of resources on the box for the instance (partly due to load), and network traffic (lots more if over the internet or WAN) - it's not a valid benchmark.  TKPROF might be more of what you're after.

Comment: While you're right about the caching of execution plans, this is not likely to make a large difference in overall execution time, unless there is very significant parsing contention on the system.  More likely what makes a large difference in elapsed time is caching of the data blocks needed to actually run the execution plan.

Answer (score 2):

To build off OMG Ponies answer, tuning based on timing is something that's possible, but not realistic.  You'd have to start either with a fully-cached buffer cache in every case, or a fully-empty buffer cache, and neither of those is going to be representative of reality - especially if there's no competing load.

When I'm tuning, it's generally against a live system with activity, and I focus on tuning logical I/Os, either through using the extended SQL trace (`dbms_monitor.session_trace_enable / dbms_monitor.session_trace_disable`) and the `tkprof` utility, or using SQL*Plus and `set autotrace traceonly` - which does all the work of the query, but throws the output away, because I'm usually not interested in watching a jillion rows scroll by.

The exact mechanism usually involves bound SQL, using something like the following:

```
 variable :my_bind1 number;
 variable :my_bind2 varchar2(30);

 begin
   :my_bind1 := 42;
   :my_bind2 := 'some meaningful string';
 end;
 /

 set timing on;
 set autotrace traceonly;

 [godawful query with binds]

 set autotrace off;
```

Within the results, I'm looking for the plan I'd expect, a comparative value for sorts - assuming any exist - and most importantly, the number of consistent I/Os.  That's how many blocks Oracle had to read in consistent mode to satisfy the query.  I can't find the original source of the quote, but I think it's Cary Milsap of Method R.

"Tune your logical I/Os, and your physical I/Os will follow."

Answer (score 1):

In performance tuning, if the only piece of data you look at is wall-clock time, you will only be getting a small part of the whole picture. You need to at least look at the execution plan, as well as IO stats, in order to work out how best to tune the query.

Also, you need to eliminate other causes of performance issues - e.g. if there is a general performance issue across many queries, it might not be the fault of just one of them - it might be an architecture problem, or significant concurrent activity on the database, or even an underlying hardware issue.

I've had similar issues to what you describe before; e.g. a certain type of query which should be very fast was taking 30 seconds to run on the first time, then would settle down to a second or two. As soon as I looked at the execution plan, however, it was obvious that it was using a full table scan, because it couldn't use the unique index that had been created. The first time the query ran, most of the data was loaded into the cache (in fact, there were two levels of cache involved - the database buffer cache, as well as a storage-level cache over the disks) so subsequent full table scans were extremely fast.

Answer (score 1):

What is correctly ?
Since 11g there are a few extra complications to take into account. The optimizer pre peeking has become a lot smarter and sql plan stability has a BIG influence. These two features make the database auto tuning but can also have unexpected effects during performance tests, for example because not all variations of the plans are known and accepted at the beginning of the tests.
This might be the cause that a second test run, the day after the first run, suddenly runs much quicker, without any apparent changes.
Since 11g performance testing is less important, compared to writing logically correct code. For example a Cartesian product and filtering out one distinct value van be functional correct but is in most of the cases wrong code because it fetches more data than logically needed.
If the queries fetches the data that is really needed and is in the correct control structure, have the database processes tune the code during the maintenance windows. In many cases the differences between the test environment and production are such that a comparison can not be safely made.
Don't get me wrong, testing is important but mostly for the logic compared to performance testing before 11g, there are extra steps to be taken.
For nice reading see [Oracle® Database 2 Day + Performance Tuning Guide 11g Release 2 (11.2)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10822/toc.htm)